# Angular ng-bind-html-unsafe expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-html2js

Hi I'm using angular and I want to do an expression in my ng-bind-html-unsafe so that it can choose between two text to show. Is this the right syntax for the expression?

```
<div  ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{ 0 && text || text2}}"></div>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQpQH/6/) that show my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without braces:

```
  <div  ng-bind-html-unsafe=" 0 && text || text2"></div>
```

Output:

```
HELLO THERE2
```

for

```
<div  ng-bind-html-unsafe=" 1 && text || text2"></div>
```

Output

```
 HELLO THERE
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQpQH/7/)</kbd>

As a side note, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is removed from newer versions. In the future it can lead to errors